# Magento - import products daily/hourly from feed and export orders to other magento website

Tags: xml, csv, magento, soap, magento-1.9

We are looking for a solution to automatically import products on an hourly basis from a csv/xml feed into a magento 1 website.

When an order is placed on this website we would then like the order exported to the supplier website (also running magento 1)

does anyone know of a simple solution or available software/extensions to achieve this please?

Comment: How are your orders exported to the supplier website? (email, API, etc.?)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.